# Is there a way to change what the go / submit button on a mobile keyboard does on a mobile web page?

Tags: javascript, android, html, iphone, mobile

We have a shopping cart form which has 3 submit buttons (one to update the quantity, one to enter a promo code, and one to finish the checkout).

On desktop the user is expected to click the submit button next to the item they are affecting and this is generally what happens, the button is close to where their mouse/keyboard focus is and the visual association is strong.

On mobile it feels more natural to click the "go" or "submit" button provided by the mobile keyboard. This submits the form using the first submit button on the page rather than the most appropriate one.

Can I change what happens when a mobile user clicks the go/submit button on their keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by disabling the submit buttons and conditionally enabling them based on which form field has the focus (only tested on iPhone so far).

On iPhone anyway the keyboard's go button submits using the first enabled submit button it finds. If there are no enabled buttons the button does nothing (wish it was removed if there is no enabled submit button but this is not the case).

Comment: This was ages ago now but I wanted to add that this method passed our Q/A departments' testing for Android and Blackberry.

Comment: This answer would be much more useful with a code example

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge here is very limited, but can't you use the `onsubmit` callback? - http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/HTML5-Development-Form--Keyboard-Events-3885651.htm#fbid=NgeGkg0S2JD

Comment: Hm. Maybe if I combine that with tracking which form field had focus when they submitted it... will poke around, thanks :)